# Class 'CDbTestCase' not found error in phpunit with yii

Tags: yii, phpunit

I am trying to implement unit testing with yii. I go to the protected\tests\unit folder and run phpunit\AccountTest

I get the error Class 'CDbTestCase' not found in ......tests\unit\AccountTest.php

I am new to unit testing and I am not sure if I set it up properly. Can someone tell me what I did wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can happen if your bootstrap.php script has incorrect paths in it.

Your protected/tests/bootstrap.php file should look like this:

```
<?php

// change the following paths if necessary
$yiit=dirname(__FILE__).'/../../../framework/yiit.php';
$config=dirname(__FILE__).'/../config/test.php';

require_once($yiit);
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/WebTestCase.php');

Yii::createWebApplication($config);
```

Notice lines 4-5. The paths will vary based on how you installed Yii and your app. Look at the locations of your files, and make sure those paths point to the correct places.

I'd also recommend running PHPUnit from inside protected/tests, not protected/tests/unit. e.g.:

```
cd protected\tests
phpunit unit\AccountTest.php
```

PHPUnit sometimes won't bootstrap correctly if run from inside the `unit` folder.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I get this. "PHP Warning:  require_once(PHPUnit/Extensions/SeleniumTestCase.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in... " I know I have to install Selenium separately . But not sure how to do this. I am using windows. Some say pear installation is not supported etc etc..

Comment: Could be that you need to add something to your PATH environment variable, or could be an incorrect file path in phpunit.bat. This thread from the Yii forum looks like it might help: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/16553-cant-get-phpunit-and-selenium-working-correctly/